# Text + Chart inside pop up window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, popup, chart

A similar question had been posted in this thread :
[Chart inside pop up window in Javascript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44800/chart-inside-pop-up-window-in-javascript)

I'm trying to do the same, but i would like to add others things in the popup (like text, feature properties, pictures, ...).
Unfortunately, when i add elements in the popup, i get [object HTMLDivElement] instead of graph.

Based on this code (http://jsfiddle.net/6UJQ4/), i wrote this :

```
m.bindPopup('text <br>' + div);
```

I think my problem is related to the fact i don't understand the writting of this statement :

```
var div = $('<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>')[0];
```

(i am totally newbie in javascript !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. For example, you can replace the following part:

```
var div = $('<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>')[0];
m.bindPopup(div);
m.openPopup();
var chart = new Charts.CircleProgress(div, "", 50, {
    font_color: "#fff",
    fill_color: "#222",
    stroke_color: "#4591C9"
});
```

with:

```
var div_chart = $('<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>');
var div_text = $('<div>Sample text</div>');
var div_img = $('<div><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Sample image" height="100" width="100"></div>');
var div_main = $('<div></div>');
div_main.append(div_text);
div_main.append(div_img);
div_main.append(div_chart);
m.bindPopup(div_main[0]);
m.openPopup();
var chart = new Charts.CircleProgress(div_chart[0], "", 50, {
    font_color: "#fff",
    fill_color: "#222",
    stroke_color: "#4591C9"
  });
```

In this example, you can put whatever you want in `div_main`. You can also control the order of objects display.

Comment: Thank you very much !
I think i will be able to adapt this to my case !
Unfortunately, i don't understand everything in this code : could you just explain me what this statement method mean : var div = $('<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>')[0]; (dollar and [0])

Comment: Well, it's a bit difficult to explain without Javascript knowledge ;) The $ is a jQuery (a javascript library) sign. Basically, it allows you to create jQuery objects that can be used to edit the DOM (HTML page structure). Here, `$('<div>...<div/>') is a HTMLDivElement, which is wrapper array of div elements. Now, `bindPopup` and `CircleProgress` don't directly take such objects as arguments, that's why you have to write `[0]` beforehand (to access the div inside the wrapper).

Comment: Thank you for this very good explanation (which will infuse into my brain gradually)

Comment: It's a very "compact" explanation ;) If you want to learn more about javascript/jQuery, I suggest you have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp) or [this one](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/jquery-ecrivez-moins-pour-faire-plus) (in French). Of course, there are many more tutorials online. Also, if my answer works for you, please consider to mark it as "accepted" (there should be a tickle below the answer's score).

Comment: I have two short supplementary questions.
I don't know if I can ask here, or if I have to open a new topic: sorry if I make the wrong choice!
As you will see on this page (http://www.parc-naturel-normandie-maine.fr/upload/gmap/observatoire/wmts/bdbocage_statscom.html), I have two problems to solve:
- position of the labels is bad (outside the main DIV)
- I have encoding problems as GeoJSON file accents displayed does not pass.
Do you know how to resolve them ?

Comment: Hem, normally you are supposed to open a new topic for each question. Unfortunately I can't really answer your label positioning problem since I'm not experienced enough with leaflet. And maybe have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery) for your encoding issue? Or it might come from the webapp settings.